# Ansible Update multiple firewall rules on Vyos

Tags: ansible, firewall

I've been trying to create a playbook that I can run periodically to go through all my Vyos firewall rules and ensure the "log enabled" command is present, just in case someone forgets to add logging to a firewall rule. I've found the **vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules** module which I think will be perfect for what I need to do.

The only problem is, is that this module requires you input the rule set name and rule number of each firewall rule that you want to update. However in my case, I want this to be done automatically and Ansible to go through each firewall rule set and associated rules that are present, and ensure logging is enabled on each rule. Something like this is what I need:

```
- name: Enable logging for each firewall rule
  vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules:
    config:
    - afi: ipv4
      rule_sets:
      - name: *all rules sets*
        rules:
        - number: *all numbers*
          log: enabled
```

I've used **vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules** to gather a dump of all rule sets and associated rules and have filtered this down to list each rule set name along with each associated rule number :

```
    - name: Get rulesets
      vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules:
        config:
        state: gathered
      register: output

    - name: Filter output and populate the list of rule set names
      debug:
        msg: "Rule set name: {{ item.0.name }}, rule number: {{ item.1.number }}"
      loop: "{{ output.gathered[0]['rule_sets'] | subelements('rules') }}"
```

This produces output like this:

```
"Rule set name: ruleset-1, rule number: 1"
"Rule set name: ruleset-1, rule number: 2"
"Rule set name: ruleset-1, rule number: 15"
"Rule set name: ruleset-1, rule number: 20"
"Rule set name: ruleset-2, rule number: 1"
"Rule set name: ruleset-2, rule number: 2"
```

I'm a bit stuck on where to go from here. I feel like I need the info filtered into a nested list like I have below, and then somehow loop the **vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules** module to update each rule set name and rule number.

```
firewall_rules:
   ruleset-1:
     1
     2
     15
     20
   ruleset-2
     1
     2
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to create a nested list, or if I even need one in the first place.

I'm relatively new to Ansible so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the dictionary first

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        firewall_rules: "{{ dict(rsets|zip(rules)) }}"
      vars:
        rsets: "{{ output.gathered.0.rule_sets|
                   map(attribute='name')|list }}"
        rules: "{{ output.gathered.0.rule_sets|
                   map(attribute='rules')|
                   map('map', attribute='number')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  firewall_rules:
    ruleset-1:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 15
    - 20
    ruleset-2:
    - 1
    - 2
```

Then use Jinja to create the structure, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: _config|from_yaml
      vars:
        _config: |-
          - afi: ipv4
            rule_sets:
          {% for set, rules in firewall_rules.items() %}
              - name: {{ set }}
                rules:
          {% for rule in rules %}
                  - number: {{ rule }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  _config|from_yaml:
  - afi: ipv4
    rule_sets:
    - name: ruleset-1
      rules:
      - number: 1
      - number: 2
      - number: 15
      - number: 20
    - name: ruleset-2
      rules:
      - number: 1
      - number: 2
```

Fit the structure to your needs and use it in the module, e.g.

```yaml
- vyos.vyos.vyos_firewall_rules:
    config: "{{ _config|from_yaml }}"
  vars:
    _config: |-
    ...
```

---

Q: ***"Output of {{ _config|from_yaml }} is not preserving the hyphens."***

A: The format you see depends on the [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#callback-plugins). If you want to see YAML set [DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback) to *yaml*

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook test-753.yml
```

or copy the content to a file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: test-753-out.yml
        content: |
          {{ _config }}
      vars:
        _config: |-
          - afi: ipv4
            rule_sets:
          {% for set, rules in firewall_rules.items() %}
              - name: {{ set }}
                rules:
          {% for rule in rules %}
                  - number: {{ rule }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat test-753-out.yml
- afi: ipv4
  rule_sets:
    - name: ruleset-1
      rules:
        - number: 1
        - number: 2
        - number: 15
        - number: 20
    - name: ruleset-2
      rules:
        - number: 1
        - number: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's almost perfect, however when I get output for **_config|from_yaml**, it's not preserving the hyphens like your output above. It's showing the data in a dictionary/list format:
`"_config|from_yaml": [{ "afi": "ipv4", "rule_sets": [`

How can I remove the curly/square brackets and the quotation marks, and instead have just hyphens like in your output?

Comment: The format you see depends on the [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#callback-plugins). Very probably you use the *default* callback plugin. The default output is JSON. If you want to see YAML use the *yaml* callback. See details ``shell> ansible-doc -t callback yaml``. But, the format of stdout is not relevant when ``config: "{{ _config|from_yaml }}"`` is used in the module. I'd expect to hear from you whether the solution is working or not in the first place.

Comment: I just tested it and it works! Apologies for not testing it earlier, I just got caught up in how the output looked before I wanted to test it on my system. Appreciate you taking the time to help me here